# Need help creating a FindMaxOverlap function

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to create a function that, given two C strings, it spits back the number of consecutive character overlap between the two strings.

For example,

```
String 1: "Today is monday."
String 2: " is monday."
```

The overlap here would be " is monday.", which is 11 characters (it includes the space and '.').

Comment: So given 2 strings, find the ordinal intersection

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer Find the beginning of the overlap and the length of it, given two stings.

Comment: so there's only 1 overlap ?

Comment: Yes.  Paul's answer works but is a bit buggy for edge cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but here's a simple approach:

```
#include <string.h>
int main() {
char s1[17] = "Today is monday.";
char s2[12] = " is monday.";

int max = 0;
int i_max = -1;
int j_max = -1;
int i = 0, j = 0, k=0;
int endl = 0, sl1, sl2;
char *ss1, *ss2;

for(i = 0; i < strlen(s1)-1; i++) {
    ss1 = s1+i;
    sl1 = strlen(ss1);

    if(max >= sl1) {
        break; // You found it.
    }

    for(j = 0; j < strlen(s2)-1; j++) {
        ss2 = s2+j;
        sl2 = strlen(ss2);

        if(max >= sl2) {
           break;    // Can't find a bigger overlap.
        }
        endl = (sl1 > sl2)?sl2:sl1;

        int n_char = 0;
        for(k = 0; k < endl+1; k++) {
            // printf("%s\t%s\n", ss1+k, ss2+k);   // Uncomment if you want to see what it compares.
            if(ss1[k] != ss2[k] || ss1[k] == '\0') {
                n_char = k;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(n_char > max) {
            max = n_char;
            i_max = i;
            j_max = j;
        }
    }
}
char nstr[max+1];
nstr[max] = '\0';
strncpy(nstr, s1+i_max, max);

printf("Maximum overlap is %d characters, substring: %s\n", max, nstr);
return 0;
}
```

**Update:** I have fixed the bugs. This definitely compiles. Here is the result: http://codepad.org/SINhmm7f
The problems were that endl was defined wrong and I wasn't checking for end-of-line conditions.

Hopefully the code speaks for itself.

Comment: Hi Paul.  I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for.  Basically, I just need to get the count of the overlap of characters between two strings.

Comment: Well, that's what the innermost function there does, I think.

Comment: I have edited mine to make it more clear how the algorithm I proposed works.

Comment: Hey, you should un-accept this answer. I just realized I was confused about strspn. It matches any characters in the entire set of s2. I'm trying to figure out what I'm thinking of.

Comment: OK, this seems to generally work now. I haven't like debugged it, but that's the general idea - count off until you find a difference.

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  It looks like it isn't taking into account spaces though?  For example, if `s1 is "mister"` and `s2 is " is "`, there shouldn't be ANY overlap between the two.  But the code is saying there is an overlap of two as it is ignoring the two spaces around `'is'`.  Other than that, it looks to work perfectly.

Comment: Fixed the bugs. It was having problems because I didn't consider the case where both lines are identical in the last position (then they both have identical null terminations, so it never sees a non-identical result and returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you need something more efficient, consider that a partial mismatch between Strings 1 and 2 means you can jump the length of the remainder of String 2 along String 1. This means you don't need to search the entirety of String 1.

Take a look at the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm). Though it is used for string searching, you could implement this algorithm for finding the maximum-length substring using String 2 as your pattern and String 1 as your target text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it will return the position of the overlap starting point, it's a bit complex, but that's how it's done in C:

```
#include <string.h>

int FindOverlap (const char * a, const char * b)
{
    // iterators
    char * u = a;
    char * v = b;
    char * c = 0; // overlap iterator

    char overlapee = 'b';

    if (strlen(a) < strlen(b)) overlapee = 'a';

    if (overlapee == 'b')
    {
        while (*u != '\0')
        {
            v = b; // reset b iterator
            c = u;
            while (*v != '\0')
            {
                if (*c != *v) break;
                c++;
                v++;
            }

            if (*v == '\0') return (u-a); // return overlap starting point
        }
    }
    else if (overlapee == 'a')
    {
        while (*v != '\0')
        {
            u = a; // reset b iterator
            c = v;
            while (*u != '\0')
            {
                if (*c != *u) break;
                c++;
                u++;
            }

            if (*v == '\0') return (v-b); // return overlap starting point
        }
    }

    return (-1); // not found
}
```